# Vba scraping img alt src

Tags: vba, image, web-scraping, src

I have question about scraping tag name like  `<img alt src = "address"` with vba.

I tried to below  but it is failed:

```
For j = 0 To opt.getElementsByTagName("img").Length - 2 Step 1

Cells(35 + i, 25 + j) = doc1.getElementsByClassName("cont")(0).getElementsBytagName("img")(i).src

Next j
```

Text:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the HTML contents as text not as snapshot?

Comment: What does "_but it is failed_" stand for? Runtime error (if so, where and which one)? Wrong result (if so, which one)?

Comment: `<img alt src="...">` is malformed, the `alt` attribute has no value, should read `<img alt="something" src="url">`, not sure if it interferes with the parsing of the DOM. You've retrieved the DOM element, it won't have a `.src` member (you're getting error 438, correct?) -- but you should be able to retrieve its attributes by name: you want the value of the `src` attribute.